# how to check the source code of stashed files without pop them in git?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have some stashed files in git, but I do not want to `git stash pop` it, because sometime it alert merge message, I do not want to do merge in order to see the source code in stashed files, is there a way of doing that?

Comment: hello, the git stash show stash@{0} only shows the files contained in this stash, but how to check source code of the stashed files?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you want the latest stashed entry,

```
git show stash@{0}:pathname
```

Two aspects of this syntax are explained in their respective manual pages:

- The `<rev>:<path>` thing is explained in the [`gitrevisions(7)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) manual page (consider reading it in its entirety — it will teach you certain convenient things to use later on).
- The `stash@{<n>}` syntax to access stash entries is explained in the [`git-stash(1)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) manual page.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get back a stashed code without remove it of the stash list you can use

```
git stash apply
```

to recover the last stashed code, but I believe you just want to see the diff, you can use

```
git diff stash@{0}
```

which is a simple command to **diff the stashed code at the first position**.

Using `git stash list` you can take a look at which *`position`* the stashed code you want to see exists and then run `git diff stash@{position}` with the proper *`position`*.

---

**EDIT** :

As stated in the comments there is another command that could help, if you want to see the whole file in a stashed code you may create a branch with the stashed code and browse at will using the following command

```
git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
```

Comment: but if I understand it correctly, the git diff only shows the different parts of two different version? if so can we see the whole file of stashed files?

Comment: I made some research but didn't find anything to fit this need, maybe the closest to this would be the stash branch, something like: `git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]` which will create a new branch with the selected stash (most recent if not informed), letting you browse the files as will.

Comment: you mean create a new local branch or remote branch?

Comment: This way it would be a local branch, without touching the remotes.

Comment: Note that `git stash branch ...` applies contents into the new branch as if you had used `git stash apply --index`, and then drops the stash.  Thus, it restores the index and work directory independently, so aside from creating the new local branch, it recovers the state from when you did the `git stash` as exactly as possible: anything you `git add`-ed is still added, etc.

Answer (score 3):

VS Code users can check the stashes along with the stashed files as below:

1. Go on `Source Control` tab
2. Click on `STASHES`.
3. You will be able to see available stashes.
4. Click on desired stash.
5. Click on desired file for which you want to check the source code. It looks similar to the screenshot attached.

[image: Stash files check]

You won't need to pop it! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, by going to `Git/Uncommitted changes/Unstash changes...`
you can see a list of the stashes. Select a stash and click on "View"